# Azure Blob: CreateCloudBlobClient' is not a member of 'CloudStorageAccount'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, azure-storage

I upgraded my web app from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5.2 and have an error that I cannot find a solution to. It is during any interface with Azure Blob Storage. I removed all NuGet Packages and added them again under 4.5.2. The error message is:

> Error  BC30456 'CreateCloudBlobClient' is not a member of 'CloudStorageAccount'.

Imports:

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Code:

```
 Private _Account As CloudStorageAccount
Private _ImageContainerName As String = ""
Private _ConnectionString As String = ""

Public Sub New(storageEndpoint As String, imageContainerName As String, Optional ByVal connStr As String = "")
    _Account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageEndpoint)
    _ImageContainerName = imageContainerName
    _ConnectionString = connStr
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property Account As CloudStorageAccount
    Get
        Return _Account
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property ImageContainerName As String
    Get
        Return _ImageContainerName
    End Get
End Property

Public Function GetImageFromStore(ByVal imageKey As String) As IO.Stream
    Dim blobStorage As CloudBlobClient = _Account.CreateCloudBlobClient


    Dim container As CloudBlobContainer = blobStorage.GetContainerReference(Me.ImageContainerName)
    If Not container.Exists Then
        container.CreateIfNotExists()
        container.SetPermissions(New BlobContainerPermissions With {.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off})
    End If

    Dim blob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(imageKey)

    Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
    'Added 11/21/2012 because the pages were erroring out when the image wasn't found in the blob.  
    If blob.Exists Then
        blob.DownloadToStream(stream)
        stream.Position = 0
    End If

    Return stream
End Function
```

Error is on this line:

```
DIm blobStorage As CloudBlobClient = _Account.CreateCloudBlobClient
```

Comment: Try Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient

Comment: Which Azure.NET SDK and Azure Storage nuget verson are you using?

Comment: Tried using the client and it doesn't allow to check to see if the file exists and it didn't return the file in a usable format.

Comment: Azure SDK is AzureSDK2.2DLLs version 1.0.0 WindowsAzure.Storage is V8.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested .Net 4.5.2 with WindowsAzure.Storage V8.3.0. All worked fine. After compare your code with mine, I found that you missed one import statement as following.

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing! Thank you!